# Al ejecutar mi código muestra errores y no hace lo requerido por la función JavaScrip

Tags: javascript, html, css

Estoy intentando agregar una cadena en un input de tipo text a una lista A y una lista B, en la cual pueda seleccionar por medio de un input de tipo radio para indicar en cual de las dos listas será agregada esta cadena, una vez agregada por medio del botón pueda colocarla o moverla a la siguiente lista, de la misma forma eliminar el registro seleccionado por medio de un botón. La función está en JavaScript, y al ejecutar no hace nada.

Dejo el código:

```js
`La función agrega la entrada del input, seleccionando la lista a la cual se quiere agregar esta cadena, 
posterior a esto seleccionar la cadena y moverla a la otra lista por medio de un botón`

        function addItem(){
          var myText = document.getElementById('Text1');
          if (myText.value ==''|| myText.value ==""){
            alert('Debes agregar');
            return;
          }

          if(document.getElementById('Radio1').checked){
            var oSelFied = document.getElementById('ListaA');
            var oOption = document.createElement("option");
            oSelFied.option.add(oOption);
            oOption.text = myText.value;
            oOption.value = myText.value;
          }else{
            var oSelFied = document.getElementById('ListaB');
            var oOption = document.createElement("option");
            oSelFied.option.add(oOption);
            oOption.text = myText.value;
            oOption.value = myText.value;
          }
          myText.value ="";
          PersistState();
          return;
        }
        function moveToLeft(){
          var e = document.getElementById("ListaB");
          var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;
          var oSelFied = document.getElementById("ListaA");
          var oOption = document.createElement("option");
          oSelFied.options.add(oOption);
          oOption.text = strUser;
          oOption.value = strUser;

          e.options.remove(e.selectedIndex);
          PersistState();
        }
        function moveToRight(){
          var e = document.getElementById("ListaA");
          var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;
          var oSelFied = document.getElementById("ListaB");
          var oOption = document.createElement("option");
          oSelFied.options.add(oOption);
          oOption.text = strUser;
          oOption.value = strUser;

          e.options.remove(e.selectedIndex);
          PersistState();
        }
        function removeA(){
          var e = document.getElementById("ListaA");
          if (e.selectedIndex >=0) {
            e.options.remove(e.selectedIndex);
            PersistState();
          }
        }
        function removeB(){
          var e = document.getElementById("ListaB");
          if (e.selectedIndex >=0) {
            e.options.remove(e.selectedIndex);
            PersistState();
          }
        }
        
        function PersistState(){
          var e = document.getElementById("ListaA");
          var f = document.getElementById("ListaB");
          var theString = "";
          for (var i = 0; i < e.options.lenght; i++){
            if (i !=(e.options.lenght-1)){
              theString +=e.options[1].text +",";
            }else{
              theString +=e.options[1].text;
            }
        }
        var theString2 = "";
        for(var i = 0; i < e.options.lenght; i++){
          if (i !=(e.options.lenght-1)){
              theString2 +=e.options[1].text +",";
          }else{
              theString2 +=e.options[1].text;
            }
        }
        sessionStorage.myListaA= theString;
        sessionStorage.myListaB = theString2;
      }

      function loadState(){
        if (sessionStorage.myListaA){
          var theString = sessionStorage.myListaA;
          var hey = theString.split(",");
          for (var i = 0; i < hey.lenght; i++){
            var oSelFied = document.getElementById("ListaA");
            var oOption = document.createElement("option");
            oSelFied.options.add(oOption);
            oOption.Text = hey[i];
            oOption.value = hey [i];
          };
        }
        if (sessionStorage.myListaB){
          var theString = sessionStorage.myListaB;
          var hey = theString.split(",");
          for (var i = 0; i < hey.lenght; i++){
            var oSelFied = document.getElementById("ListaB");
            var oOption = document.createElement("option");
            oSelFied.options.add(oOption);
            oOption.Text = hey[i];
            oOption.value = hey [i];
      }
    }
  }
```

```css
`Mis estilos`
 #caja{ background-color: gray; border: outset #777; height: 500px;  width: 500px; margin: auto;  padding: 15px; margin-top: 100px;}
           .la{ float: left;}
           .lb{float: right;}
            #btns{margin-top: 30px; margin-left: 150px;}
            input{ margin-right: 10px; margin-left: 15px;}
            select{width: 150px; margin-top: 20px;}
```

```html
<body  onload="loadState();" style="background: #ecf0f1;">
<div id="caja">
                Ordenes de Produccion:<input id="Text1" type="text" /><br>
                          ListaA<input id="Radio1" type="radio" name="Lista" value="ListaA" checked="checked"><br>
                          ListaB<input id="Radio2" type="radio" name="Lista" value="ListaB"/>
                          <input type="button" id="btnAgregar" value="Agregar" onclick="addItem();"/><br><br>
                          
                          <input class="la" type="button" value="EliminarA" id="btnEliminarA" onclick="removeA();"/>
                          <input class="lb" type="button" value="EliminarB" id="btnEliminarB" onclick="removeB();"/>

                          <select class="la" name="ListaA" id="ListaA" size="10"></select>
                          <select class="lb" name="ListaB" id="ListaB" size="10"></select>
                          
                          <div id="btns">
                            <input type="button" value=">>" id="btntoRigth" name="btnToRigth" onclick="moveToRight();">
                          </div>
                        </div>
                        </body>
```

Comment: Ahora, edita el títutlo de la pregunta, y en el cuerpo del mensaje, agrega los detalles del error, lectura sugerida: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822 Saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu función está bien, quizá debes poner mas atención a los errores que te da la consola. Estás usando `add()` de forma incorrecta: `oSelFied.option.add(oOption);` cuando la forma adecuada es `oSelFied.add(oOption);`

Modifiqué todos tus **`add()`**, quizá debas probar de esta forma:

```html
<style>
    #caja{ background-color: gray; border: outset #777; height: 500px;  width: 500px; margin: auto;  padding: 15px; margin-top: 100px;}
    .la{ float: left;}
    .lb{float: right;}
    #btns{margin-top: 30px; margin-left: 150px;}
    input{ margin-right: 10px; margin-left: 15px;}
    select{width: 150px; margin-top: 20px;}
</style>

<body style="background: #ecf0f1;">
    <div id="caja">
        Ordenes de Produccion:<input id="Text1" type="text" /><br>
        ListaA<input id="Radio1" type="radio" name="Lista" value="ListaA" checked="checked"><br>
        ListaB<input id="Radio2" type="radio" name="Lista" value="ListaB"/>
        <input type="button" id="btnAgregar" value="Agregar" onclick="addItem();"/><br><br>
        
        <input class="la" type="button" value="EliminarA" id="btnEliminarA" onclick="removeA();"/>
        <input class="lb" type="button" value="EliminarB" id="btnEliminarB" onclick="removeB();"/>

        <select class="la" name="ListaA" id="ListaA" size="10"></select>
        <select class="lb" name="ListaB" id="ListaB" size="10"></select>
        
        <div id="btns">
        <input type="button" value=">>" id="btntoRigth" name="btnToRigth" onclick="moveToRight();">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

<script>

    function addItem(){
        var myText = document.getElementById('Text1');
        if (myText.value ==''|| myText.value ==""){
            alert('Debes agregar');
            return;
        }

        if(document.getElementById('Radio1').checked){
            var oSelFied = document.getElementById('ListaA');
            var oOption = document.createElement("option");
            oSelFied.add(oOption);
            oOption.text = myText.value;
            oOption.value = myText.value;
        }else{
            var oSelFied = document.getElementById('ListaB');
            var oOption = document.createElement("option");
            oSelFied.add(oOption);
            oOption.text = myText.value;
            oOption.value = myText.value;
        }
        myText.value ="";
        PersistState();
        return;
    }
    function moveToLeft(){
        var e = document.getElementById("ListaB");
        var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;
        var oSelFied = document.getElementById("ListaA");
        var oOption = document.createElement("option");
        oSelFied.add(oOption);
        oOption.text = strUser;
        oOption.value = strUser;

        e.options.remove(e.selectedIndex);
        PersistState();
    }
    function moveToRight(){
        var e = document.getElementById("ListaA");
        var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;
        var oSelFied = document.getElementById("ListaB");
        var oOption = document.createElement("option");
        oSelFied.add(oOption);
        oOption.text = strUser;
        oOption.value = strUser;

        e.options.remove(e.selectedIndex);
        PersistState();
    }
    function removeA(){
        var e = document.getElementById("ListaA");
        if (e.selectedIndex >=0) {
        e.options.remove(e.selectedIndex);
        PersistState();
        }
    }
    function removeB(){
        var e = document.getElementById("ListaB");
        if (e.selectedIndex >=0) {
        e.options.remove(e.selectedIndex);
        PersistState();
        }
    }
    
    function PersistState(){
        var e = document.getElementById("ListaA");
        var f = document.getElementById("ListaB");
        var theString = "";
        for (var i = 0; i < e.options.lenght; i++){
        if (i !=(e.options.lenght-1)){
            theString +=e.options[1].text +",";
        }else{
            theString +=e.options[1].text;
        }
    }
    var theString2 = "";
    for(var i = 0; i < e.options.lenght; i++){
        if (i !=(e.options.lenght-1)){
            theString2 +=e.options[1].text +",";
        }else{
            theString2 +=e.options[1].text;
        }
    }
    sessionStorage.myListaA= theString;
    sessionStorage.myListaB = theString2;
    }

    function loadState(){
        if (sessionStorage.myListaA){
            var theString = sessionStorage.myListaA;
            var hey = theString.split(",");
            for (var i = 0; i < hey.lenght; i++){
            var oSelFied = document.getElementById("ListaA");
            var oOption = document.createElement("option");
            oSelFied.add(oOption);
            oOption.Text = hey[i];
            oOption.value = hey [i];
            };
        }
        if (sessionStorage.myListaB){
            var theString = sessionStorage.myListaB;
            var hey = theString.split(",");
            for (var i = 0; i < hey.lenght; i++){
                var oSelFied = document.getElementById("ListaB");
                var oOption = document.createElement("option");
                oSelFied.add(oOption);
                oOption.Text = hey[i];
                oOption.value = hey [i];
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Ok! si gracias por la observación, y corrección te lo agradezco identifique el error en la función.

Comment: Que bueno que te haya servido. Si la respuesta solucionó tu problema, no olvides marcarla como correcta, en caso de que no, indícalo en los comentarios para aportarte otra respuesta. Saludos

Comment: ok si pero si quiero mover 5 registros en una misma lista de arriba para abajo o en lo contrario abajo para arriba , la función seria parecida a moveToLeft y moveToRight ?

Comment: Así es, es parecido